# Ito Lemma on $d\left(\frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} W_u \, du\right)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I recently learnt Ito's lemma but I am slightly confused when using it. I would appreciate any worked answers for the following problem:

Determine
$$d\left(\frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} W_u \, du\right)$$
where $W_u$ is the Brownian motion.

I have Ito's lemma $df(t,X_t) = \partial_tf(t,X_t)dt + \partial_xf(t,X_t)dx + \frac{1}{2}\partial^2_xf(t,X_t)(dX_t)^2$

I would set $\frac{1}{t}$ in my question as the term $t$ in Ito's lemma and $\int_{0}^{t} W_u \,du$ as $X_t$

For instance what is $\partial^2_x(\int_{0}^{t}W_u\,du)$?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: In your case, if $f(t,x)= \frac{x}{t}$, then $\partial^2_x f(t,x)=0$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth may I know why did you not choose $X_t = W_t$? Why did you choose $X_t = \int_{0}^{t} W_u \, du$ instead?
Is it because choosing $X_t = W_t$ would make the application of Ito's lemma more complicated?

Comment: We apply Ito lemma to a function $f$ using Ito process $Y_t$ such that $f(Y_t)$ is again an Ito process (assuming that $f$ meets the necessary conditions). In your case we cannot write $\frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} W_u \, du = f(t, W_t)$.

Comment: @Sesame Thanks for the clarification! $\int_0^t W_u \, du$ not only depends on $W_t$ but $(W_s : 0 \leq s \leq t)$ so we cannot just consider Ito Lemma wrt $W_t$ only but we have to consider $\forall s \in [0,t]$